# webscraping to a pandas DF

Tags: python-3.x

Appologize if this has been asked before i am trying to scrape web reviews into a dataframe. The problem I have is that it scrapes the same review 10 times and not 10 different reviews.

'''
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.marriott.com/hotels/hotel-reviews/amsnt-amsterdam-marriott-hotel'

```
for page in range(10):
page = requests.get("https://www.marriott.com/hotels/hotel-reviews/amsnt-amsterdam-marriott-hotel")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

general_data = soup.find_all(class_='bvseo-review')
i = 1
first = general_data[i]
i+=1

for item in general_data:
    span = first.find_all('span')
    description = first.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'description'})
    rating = first.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'ratingValue'})
    auteur = first.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'author'})

pagereviews = pd.DataFrame({
    "description":description,
    "ratingValue":rating,
    "author":auteur
})

pagereviews
```

'''

the result would be that the DF would contain 10 unique reviews.

Comment: shouldnt it be item.find_all instead of first.find_all?

Comment: the first would rever to 'first = general_data[i]'. I was hoping i could raise the index of general_data so it would output general_data[i+=1]

If i would change general_data[1] to general_data[2] it does give a different output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace the for loop with

```
span = []
description = []
rating = []
auteur = []
for item in general_data:
    span.append(item.find_all('span'))
    description.append(item.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'description'}))
    rating.append(item.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'ratingValue'}))
    auteur.append(item.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'author'}))
```

Comment: wow, this worked like a charm! Can you maybe clarify a little why this is suddenly giving me the correct output? Im still new to python and i am trying to understand the code as best i can.

Comment: sure. 
1. Define the lists to hold the data.
2. Iterate over general_data.
3. For each iteration, extract the results from find_all and append to the list